# ASP.Net printing without dialog box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing

I want my web application to print w popup page just after appearance automatically without asking the client to choose with printer to be choose.

how can I handle silent printing in ASP.Net with java-script or ajax or what is the most suitable solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't and for good reasons, such as:

- The user should always be able to choose which printer they want to use.
- The user should always be able to choose whether they print something or not (imagine the spam that would constantly fly out of your printer otherwise)

Comment: It could also possibly be done with Flash, Silverlight or a java applet but that didn't seem to be what you were asking. Will this be used in a business environment where you have control of users software?

Comment: yes it is, this application is in a company which have about 300 branch and print daily thousands of papers so it wast time for the user to always press ctrl+P the choose the printer the press print for each paper .. i hope i could fine a solution for this as it's very critical to me

Answer (score 0):

Some third party controls are available for this(in WPF). Please check whether this is useful in asp.net also.

http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/dotnet/n_wpf_printing.printing.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
//OnTouchPrint.aspx.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TokenPrint
{
    public partial class Try : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            }

        }

         private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
           {

                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                SolidBrush Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                string printText = TextBox1.Text;
                g.DrawString(printText, new Font("arial", 12), Brush, 10, 10);

            }


        protected void Press_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmddHHMM");
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
                ps.PrintToFile = true;
               // ps.PrintFileName = "D:\\PRINT\\Print_"+Time+".oxps"; /* you can save file here */
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pd = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
                System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController printControl = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
                pd.PrintController = printControl;
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                pd.PrinterSettings = ps;
                pd.Print();
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Printed Successfully.Check: Drive D')", true);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Try.aspx");
        }
    }
}

//OnTouchPrint.aspx

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OnTouchPrint.aspx.cs" Inherits="TokenPrint.Try" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="235px" Height="142px" 
        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>


    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Empty message can not be printed!" 
        ValidationGroup="vgp1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Press" runat="server" Text="Press" onclick="Press_Click" 
        ValidationGroup="vgp1" />


    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Refresh" 
        ValidationGroup="vgp2" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is significant for a good answer if you're not only putting working code into it, but also explaining your code (steps to the solution) to the OP.

Comment: Ohh..Its serverside printing not client side .
And i got printer not found when i host this solution on server and use it with client.